# How do I check in a TFS solution to VSO?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to move a solution from TFS to VSO. We're not migrating it on the server, I'm just trying to check it in new under VSO. I went into the .sln & .csproj files and removed all the SCC sections. I then opened the solution and tried to change the SCC it is in. But while it shows the correct values for the Server Name and Binding, it's saying invalid and only wants to check in the .vssscc files it's creating.

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1) create a workspace for t new VSO server

2) Copy the files into the folder structure that you want under that new workspace

3) open the solution

4) File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control

5) Unmap all of the projects and solution

6) remap

You should then be able to check in everything...

Comment: I did all that. Unfortunately it's telling me that it's invalid when I bind them to the new VSO project location.

Comment: I posted a screenshot to the question. TIA.

Comment: The error that you are getting signifies that the files are not stored in a workspace mapped to that tfs server. Can you run "tf workspaces" and make sure that you don't have dups or inconsistencies...

Comment: I found a solution. I unbind, then exit Visual Studio. Then re-start Visual Studio and have the choice to add them to the new workspace. That works. The key is exiting Visual Studio after the unbind.